# prove that locally minimal solution to n-town problem has roads meeting at 2pi/3

Tags: proof-writing, stability-in-odes

For the n-town problem when n is 3 and the nodes may not necessarily form an equalateral triangle, I'm trying to prove that the angle between 2 adjacent roads is always 2pi/3 in the locally minimum solution (with one internal node).

I have proved that the sum of the unit vectors in the direction of the 3 roads (represented as vectors) is the zero vector. I have tried to manipulate the equality using the dot product but can't seem to prove it.

Comment: I believe you need all angles of the outer triangle to be less than $120^\circ$

Comment: Firstly if the nodes were A,B and C do you mean the outer triangle to be ABC? and secondly how can i use this to show that the angles are 2pi/3?

Comment: Yes. If ABC are collinear or too close to collinear, I don't think this works